# Stop watch calculation (convert 00:00) to 00:00

Tags: c#, stopwatch

I face off a small problem, it is a simple stopwatch but I want to save the last date every time when program closed it or click stop, to calculate time for every time I clicked start until I stopped something like manufacturing time.

As an example: if I clicked start today for 5 seconds, then I closed the program, I want to save 5 seconds.

Then when I reopen the program, it starts from zero but makes summation 5 seconds.

- Second Time = first time + second Time
- Second time = 05+000
  ..

If I clicked start for 8 second, it would become:

- second time = 8  + 5 = 13

If I closed the program and reopened it and click start for 7 second

- second time = 7 + 13 = 20 seconds

but all time I convert it in ("HH:mm: ss")

It became like that

```
00:00:00 converts to 2/23/2020 12:00:00 AM.
```

I want it to convert to 00:00:00 without any date (month, year ...)

Because when I make summation it gives me the wrong number.

```
System.Timers.Timer t;
int D, H, m, s;
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime Drawing;
DateTime Rent;
long Machine_time;

public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        Rent = Properties.Settings.Default.Drawing_Time;
}

private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        t.Start();
}

private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        t.Stop();

        try
        {
            // Drawing = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox1.Text, @"HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Drawing = DateTime.Parse(textBox1.Text);
          //  Drawing = DateTime.Now.ToString( @"HH:mm:ss");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", textBox1.Text, Drawing.ToString());
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", textBox1.Text);
        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.Drawing_Time = Drawing;

        long elapsedTicks = Drawing.Ticks ;
        Machine_time = elapsedTicks + Machine_time;
        TimeSpan elapsedSpan = new TimeSpan(Machine_time);
        MessageBox.Show(Drawing.ToString());

        string message = elapsedSpan.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(message);

        saveSettings();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
       Properties.Settings.Default.Machine_Time = Machine_Time ;

        saveSettings();
        t.Stop();
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    public void saveSettings()
    {
        try
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved Settings");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Save Settings: " + e);
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t = new System.Timers.Timer();
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Elapsed += onTimeEvent;
    }

    private void onTimeEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        { 
            s += 1;

            if (s == 60)
            {
                s = 0;
                m += 1;
            }

            if (m == 60)
            {
                m = 0;
                H += 1;
            }

            if (H == 24)
            {
                H = 0;
                D += 1;
            }

            labelResult.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", D.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), H.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), m.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), s.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
            textBox1.Text= string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}",  H.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), m.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), s.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
        }));
}
```

Comment: If you'd used a Windows Forms timer you wouldnt have had to Invoke

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I donot think my problem for invoke. I will rewrite the code on timer , it is not problem .

Comment: Indeed, i never said that was the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using `DateTime` for keeping the "accumulated time" or how much time has passed. Don't use DateTime for that. DateTime as the name says, is for keeping DATE and TIME parts and when you think "how much time has passed since 5 days ago?" you dont answer such question with "5th of May". You need something that does not care about calendar dates. Just time itself.

What you want to use is `TimeSpan`, that's an **interval** of time, without dates. This data type simply describes how much time has passed. You won't find "13th February" there since month-days are used for describing time-points, not time-intervals. In `TimeSpan` the time interval is described as seconds/minutes/hours/days and, well, that's about that. Lengths of a year/month varies depending on various things, so it's not a good unit for time-interval. One can argue that "a week" is always 7 days long, ok, we could use it as well, but TimeSpan doesn't have weeks. A `day` is a last unit in a `TimeSpan`.

Play a bit with the `TimeSpan` and most probably you will solve everything on your own and have more fun coding.

Oh, you may also want to notice that you can subtract DateTime. A datetime minus another datetime returns you a TimeSpan value. Handy.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is quite a complicated program, it seems, for what it is.. It would be simpler to just use datetimes:

```
private DateTime _startTime = DateTime.MinValue;

public Form1()
{
        InitializeComponent();
}

private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        _startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
}

private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        StopStopwatch(true);
}

private void StopStopwatch(bool showErrorMessages)
{
        if(_startTime > DateTime.MinValue)
            Properties.Settings.Default.ElapsedTotalSeconds += (DateTime.UtcNow - _startTIme).TotalSeconds;
        else if(showErrormessages)
            MessageBox.Show("Stopwatch isn't running");

        _startTIme = DateTime.MinValue; //if minvalue it means the stopwatch isn't running
}

private void Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Properties.Settings.Default.ElapsedTotalSeconds = 0;
}        


private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
        StopStopwatch(false);
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}


//if you want a visual feedback the timer is running, have a timer that you start and stop with the click events, and update a label in its tick event
private void Timer_Tick(...) //its a windows forms timer, not a system timers timer
{
        if(_startTIme > DateTime.MinValue){

          TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Properties.Settings.Default.ElapsedTotalSeconds);

          ts += (DateTime.UtcNow - _startTime);

          Label1.Text = ts.ToString();

        }
}
```

That's all you need to manage the nuts and bolts of this:

- Record the time when someone clicks start
- When someone clicks stop, do the current time minus the start time and get the totalseconds out of the resulting timespan. Mark the stopwatch as not running so if they click stop again it doesnt add again
- Store those seconds into the settings save (note: must be user scope setting, should be double type)
- If they quit the app while the timer is running, stop the timer, add the seconds, save the settings, close the app

Provide a reset mechanism.

If you want some sort of visual feedback the timer is running, see the bottom of the code - it's a timer that will repeatedly update a label with the current total time derived from a TimeSpan based on the Settings value, plus a TimeSpan based on the difference between when start was clicked, and now. The label will update every time the timer tiks. If you want tit to update 10 times a second, make the timer interval 100ms

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for who guide me yes I just replace DateTime to TimeSpane, but yes it have some limit thing for a week but I can figure out with it. thanks again

and this modification code

```
  private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Stop();
          try
        {
            Drawing_time =  TimeSpan.Parse (labelResult.Text);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", labelResult.Text, Drawing_time.ToString());
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", labelResult.Text);
        }
         Machine_time = Drawing_time + Machine_time;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Machine_Time = Machine_time;
       MessageBox.Show(Drawing_time.ToString());
        string message = "Full Time   " + ((Machine_time)).ToString() + "\n" +"Days   " +((Machine_time.Days)).ToString() + "\n" + "Hours   "+((Machine_time.Hours)).ToString() + "\n"
         + "Minutes  " + ((Machine_time.Minutes)).ToString()+ "\n"+ "Seconds  " + ((Machine_time.Seconds)).ToString();
     MessageBox.Show(message);
        saveSettings();
    }
```